# quoting problem when piping find output into xargs

Tags: find, filenames, xargs

I have a directory with the following subdirectories, i.e. If I run `$ tree -L 1`

```
.
├── 2007-06-20_to_2008-10-01
├── 2008-07-21_to_2008_08_12-Nokia 2mp
├── 2009-11-01_to_2011-01-10 - All iphone Pics
├── 2011-01-01 palliser-pics
├── 2011-03-10_to_2011-04-12-few iphone pics b4 switch to HTC
└── 2011-03-31-to-2013-05-01 ALL HTC pics-backup-prior-to-factory-reset
```

I would like to see the amount of diskspace those 2 directories and all their contents take up.
e.g. desired output, something like

```
2.7G  2007-06-20_to_2008-10-01
200MB 2008-07-21_to_2008_08_12-Nokia 2mp
1.3G  2009-11-01_to_2011-01-10 - All iphone Pics
667MB 2011-01-01 palliser-pics
2.3G  2011-03-10_to_2011-04-12-few iphone pics b4 switch to HTC
123MB 2011-03-31-to-2013-05-01 ALL HTC pics-backup-prior-to-factory-reset
```

So I have been trying:

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs du -h
```

but because some of the directory names contain spaces  each line from the `find` output is producing many `WORD`'s before being passed to `xargs`, is it possible to fix this?

I know the root cause of the problem is caused by the spaces in the files, and I will use `rename` to fix if I cant find a way to get disksize with `du`, `find` and `xargs`

Comment: `find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec du -h {} +`

Comment: thanks its an improvement, but that command is listing out all the subdirectories - and then seems to be looping back and re-producing *that* output another 4 or 5 times

Comment: ah you edited your comment.  using `{} +` seemed to fix the looping issue - but its still printing the subdir's?

Comment: yeah, `du` does its own path traversal. user `du -sh` to *summarize* each argument.

Comment: then that summarises too much - it only `du` once producing one line of output containing the grand total for all directories. I guess `-exec` is the only option - but its obviously tricky to predict what arguments its going to use

Comment: how many directories per `find` match do you want exactly then?

Comment: just the top level dirs only, depth = 1. I have updated the question to show desired output

Comment: use `find . -path '*/*/*/*' -prune -type -d -exec du -sh {} +`

Comment: @mikeserv Using your ideas I finally got `find . -maxdepth 1  -type d  -execdir du -sh {}  +` to work thanks - if you post as an answer - I would accept it

Comment: you didn't use my ideas. i never suggested you do anything like that. what was wrong with `-parg '*/*/*/*'`? but *you* can post an answer, too, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find | xargs` should always be used in conjunction with `-print0` and `-0`, as explained in `man find`:

```
   -print0
          True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed
          by a null character (instead of the newline character that
          -print uses).  This allows file names that contain newlines or
          other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by
          programs that process the find output.  This option corresponds
          to the -0 option of xargs.
```

Thus you want:
`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 du -sh`
or without `find` and with a sufficiently evolved shell (`zsh`):
`print -N *(/) | xargs -0 du -sh`
leading you to the even simpler:
`du -sh *(/)`

Comment: Nice one , thanks. I had seen the `print0` previously but didn't know what it was used for.

Comment: @kos: Is not; the root `.` is at depth 0, and we want to get rid of it.  That's what other commentators did with `! -name . -prune`.

Comment: My bad, sorry, I missed that point.

Comment: Although this is arguably not a nice behavior from `du` that `du -s a a/b` only prints the value for `a`.  I'll report that.